# Percorrer em tabelas LUA

Tags: lua

Tenho duas tabelas criadas em LUA. Quero percorrer se existe um valor igual entre as duas. Algo deste genero.

```
table1={5,10,30,40,50,60,40}
table2={10,30,40}
for i=1,#table1 do
  if table1[i]==table2[i] then
    print("valor igual")
  end
end
```

O problema é que como a tabela 1 é maior que a dois, não vai conseguir percorrer a tabela toda. Como posso adaptar isso?

Comment: As tabelas são necessariamente tabelas de inteiros? Você tem como garantir que elas estão ordenadas? Você pode pagar o custo de ordená-las se elas não estiverem ordenadas?

Comment: Isto é um exemplo, até estou a utilisar com strings. As tabelas não podem ser ordenadas porque são da maneiro como são inseridas.

Comment: Por que você quer saber isso? Qual o problema real que você quer resolver com esse passo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você não tem espaço nem em memória nem em disco para criar uma cópia ordenada de nenhuma das duas tabelas, não tem jeito: você precisa de dois `for`s:

```
for i=1,#table1 do
  for j=1,#table2 do
    if table1[i]==table2[j] then
      print("valor igual")
    end
  end
end
```

(note a diferença nos índices)

Obviamente, o problema é que se você não pode pagar o custo de ordenar as tabelas, isso provavelmente implica que elas são gigantes, e portanto o algoritmo acima é O(m n), que é um custo que você *também* não pode pagar, a menos que por algum motivo tempo de processamento seja *muito* mais barato que disco e/ou memória.

O que você *pode* fazer nesse caso é uma abordagem probabilística: você pode criar um [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) (inglês), popular com os elementos de uma tabela e consultar todos os elementos da outra tabela contra esse bloom filter; a vantagem é que isso é muito econômico em tempo/memória, mas você cria o risco de um falso positivo — o algoritmo pode dizer que as tabelas têm elementos em comum quando elas não tem (mas se o algoritmo disser que as tabelas **não** têm elementos em comum, é garantido que isso é verdade).

---

Se você pode ordenar *uma* das tabelas, você pode fazer uma [busca binária](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BinarySearch) de cada elemento da tabela não-ordenada na tabela ordenada, o que tem complexidade O(m log n), onde n é o tamanho da tabela ordenada; naturalmente, você deve sempre que possível, ordenar a tabela maior.

---

Se você pode ordenar *ambas* as tabelas, você pode fazer isso:

```
i = 1
j = 1
while i <= #table1 and j <= #table2 do
    if table1[i] < table2[j] then
        i = i + 1
    else if table2[j] < table1[i] then
        j = j + 1
    else
        print("valor igual")
        break
    end
end
```

A ideia é que, como as listas são ordenadas, se o menor elemento da primeira tabela for menor que o menor elemento da segunda tabela, ele nunca vai ser igual a nenhum elemento da segunda tabela, e portanto pode ser descartado.

Se você realmente precisar espremer a performance dessa comparação, tem um [*paper* do Ricardo Baeza-Yates](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-27801-6_30) que trata de algoritmos de interseção de listas ordenadas.

---

Se as duas listas forem minúsculas, os dois `for`s do começo dessa resposta são a melhor solução — as firulas que as outras soluções envolvem vão acabar custando mais do que fazer todas as comparações entre todos os pares de valores.

Answer (score 2):

Se você pode criar uma outra tabela, experimente isso:

```
table1={5,10,30,40,50,60,40}
table2={10,30,40}

values={}
for k,v in pairs(table1) do
    values[v]=true
end
for k,v in pairs(table2) do
    if values[v] then
        print(v)
    end
end
```

Esse método gasta tempo e memória *O(m+n)*.

Comment: (e provavelmente vai rodar mais rápido que a comparação de listas ordenadas, já que a maioria das comparações é de inteiros e não de strings)

Answer (score 1):

Este modo percorre as duas tabelas. O índice da primeira servirá como ordenador e o índice da segunda servirá como controlador. O ordenador conta e apresenta os itens e o controlador verifica se os valores são ou não são iguais.
Claro que é somente um modelo dentre inúmeros.

```
table1={5,10,30,40,50,60,40}
table2={10,30,40}
for i=1,#table1 do
    for j=1,#table2 do
        if table1[i]==table2[j] then
            num1, num2 = table1[i], table2[j]
            print(string.format("%d e valor igual a %d",table1[i],table2[j]))
        end
    end
end
```

Saída:

```
10 e valor igual a 10
30 e valor igual a 30
40 e valor igual a 40
40 e valor igual a 40
```